# Continue to deploy project after prerequisites installation

Tags: c#, windows-installer, setup-project, setup-deployment, deployment-project

I have a simple VS Deployment Project that gathers all the files I need and packs it to MSI package. The project also creates .EXE that checks if VSTO installed on a computer and if not - specific launch condition fired (user downloads and installs VSTO  from InstallUrl link).

The issue here is that user should execute my installation .EXE file again after all prerequisites will be installed (VSTO in my case). How can I continue installation of my app automatically right after my prerequisites finish its installation? Is it possible to achieve only with VS Deployment Project?

Comment: The default normal behavior with the bootstrapper setup.exe( from the setup project) is to install the prerequisites and then your MSI file. So yes, it's possible and normal, but is there any error message, or anything at all that indicates why setup.exe doesn't install your MSI after the prerequisites?

Answer (score 0):

The solution for the problem was found in using native VSTO (Project properties -> Prerequisites -> check VSTO) instead of using custom launch condition + sending a user to InstallUrl link. In this case .EXE automatically verificates VSTO version and installs it if needed. After VSTO installation it continues main installation process seamlessly.

Nevertheless the solution does not solve the problem for custom prerequisites.